# Magento 2, How to respond array in API without sort

Tags: magento2.2, api

Using `Magento 2.2`, `API`. I need to return array sort by **value** but although I try to *sort by value* the result still return array *sort by key*.

**CODE**

```
$listStore = array();
// Store locator collection
$storeLocatorCollection = $this->getStoreCollection($storeRestriction);
$storeLocatorCollection->setCurPage(0);
$storeLocatorCollection->setPageSize(null);

foreach ($storeLocatorCollection->prepareJson() as $store) {
    if (isset($store['storelocator_id'])) {
        $storeId = $store['store_id'];
        $storeLocator = $this->storeLocatorFactory->create()->load($store['storelocator_id']);
        // Location
        $latitude = $storeLocator->getData('latitude');
        $longitude = $storeLocator->getData('longitude');

        $distant = 0;
        if (null != $storeRestriction->getLatitude() && null != $storeRestriction->getLongitude()) {
            $distant = $this->mapUtil->greatCircleDistance($latitude, $longitude,
            $storeRestriction->getLatitude(), $storeRestriction->getLongitude());
            $distant = $distant / 1000; // Convert m to km;
        }
    }
    $listStore[$storeId] = $distant;
}

asort($listStore);
```

**ARRAY listStore**

```
[23]    2.4107568853165 
[20]    3.3449976265865 
[21]    3.4099968711001 
[18]    3.4131865924907 
[15]    3.9950328677024 
[19]    4.1591698565672 
[11]    4.1692511579133 
[12]    4.2306940706562 
[2]     4.2889366130284 
[6]     4.3575747958034 
[8]     4.4132784969975 
[10]    4.4158903167744 
[5]     4.4233937790811 
[16]    4.5939586847546 
[4]     4.675968479996  
[3]     4.8981886399144 
[9]     5.0217300555084 
[22]    5.4732324269605 
[17]    5.4825053338869 
[7]     5.5024903893259 
[14]    5.8161618466356 
[25]    8.1384613125899 
[24]    11.943478996118
```

**ARRAY Respond**

```
[
    {
        "2": 4.2889366130284,
        "3": 4.8981886399144,
        "4": 4.675968479996,
        "5": 4.4233937790811,
        "6": 4.3575747958034,
        "7": 5.5024903893259,
        "8": 4.4132784969975,
        "9": 5.0217300555084,
        "10": 4.4158903167744,
        "11": 4.1692511579133,
        "12": 4.2306940706562,
        "14": 5.8161618466356,
        "15": 3.9950328677024,
        "16": 4.5939586847546,
        "17": 5.4825053338869,
        "18": 3.4131865924907,
        "19": 4.1591698565672,
        "20": 3.3449976265865,
        "21": 3.4099968711001,
        "22": 5.4732324269605,
        "23": 2.4107568853165,
        "24": 11.943478996118,
        "25": 8.1384613125899
    }
]
```